# How add minutes to current time of datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I try to modify the datetimepicker but can't figure out how could add x minutes to current datetime and use it as mintime. Unfortuantely, there's no minTime parameter...

Any advice how could I achieve it. Thank you in advance.

```
$('input').filter('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ minDate: 0, stepMinute: 15 });
```

Comment: jQuery UI doesn't have a datetimepicker. What plugin are you using?

Comment: You have to specify the plugin you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using this one: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: You can use getMinutes() and setMinutes() I guess

Comment: Thanks, managed to achieve it. But I'd like to user minDate and setDate together, but it's not really working... Demo: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9z7Zw/4/) Any advice?